# Mvc Telerik Button Event

Tags: button, telerik, telerik-mvc, mouseclick-event

I want to navigate to another action NewPage in Home Controller when somebody click on the following button.

```
<input class="t-button AlignButton" type="button" value="New" />
```

What would be the code for performing this action.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be better to use an ActionLink.

```
@Html.ActionLink("New", "NewPage", "Home")
```

If you want it to look like a button, you can add css properties.

```
@Html.ActionLink("New", "NewPage", "Home", new { @class="newpage" })
```

In the css, you can define what you want the link to look like including using an image.

Answer (score 1):

I use such solutions:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Button()
    .Name("CreateDataSubmit")
    .Content("Create new")
    .Events(e => e.Click(@<text>function(e) { window.location.href = "@(Url.Action("Create"))" }</text>))
)

@Html.ActionLink("Create new", "Create", null, new { @class = "k-button k-button-icontext" })
```

The second one is better. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

There are few options. You can do what Daniel suggested or you could do it using JavaScript.

*Note* navigation would not work in a browser that doesn't have JavaScript capability.

Add Id to the button

```
<input class="t-button AlignButton" type="button" value="New" id="my-button" url="@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")" />
```

Use JavaScript to find the button and do the url change. Here is a jQuery version

```
$(document).ready(function () {        
    $('#my-button').click(function (e) { 
        var url = $(this).attr('url');
        windows.location = url;
    });
});
```